# Emoji Not Displaying | DIscord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have an emoji in my bot's support server, and I wanted to use it for my bot. It doesn't work. Instead of showing the emoji, it shows the `:greenTick:` text instead.

I am using `<a:greenTick:id>` (`id` is the id itself.)

Even for me, trying to use it in my server, the text changes to a `:greenTick:`

**The emoji is not animated**

Example:

```py
@client.command()
async def example_cmd(ctx):
    await ctx.send("<a:greenTick:1234567890> | Don't mind the id of the emoji, its fake."
```

My real emoji's id is correct. I got it from its emoji link (**COPY LINK** context menu button).

Is this problem related with how discord works?

Please do answer.

Thanks in advance,

Beedful

Comment: If the emoji is not animated, why have the `a`? Custom non-animated emojis are formatted as `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>`. Do also ensure that your bot shares the same server as the emoji you're trying to use.

Comment: You can find the correct `name:id` by doing a `\` before sending the emoji, then send the message and the output will show the correct `name:id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is having an `a` before the name, to use emojis we use:

```
<:Name:1234567890>
```

The `a` is used only for animated emojis, that's why it doesn't work with yours, because it's not animated.